# Converting image to grayscale returned a weird image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I tried to convert an rgb image to grayscale using the weighted sum formula

Y' = 0.299 R' + 0.587 G' + .114 B'

It didn't give any errors but I am unable to understand the output.
Here's the code:

```
img = Image.open("dog.jpg")
img = img.resize((256, 256), resample=Image.BILINEAR)
img = np.array(img)
bw = np.zeros((256,256))
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        bw[i,j] = (.299*img[i,j,0])+(.587*img[i,j,1])+(.114*img[i,j,2])
i = Image.fromarray(bw,'L')
```

Here is the output picture that I got:

[image: Output picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation in `bw[i,j]` results in a float. Images expect a uint8 type, i.e., integers in the range 0-255. To fix this change

```
bw = np.zeros((256,256))
```

to

```
bw = np.zeros((256,256), dtype=np.uint8)
```

This will clip every number in 0-0.999... to 0.

```
>>> bw[0,0] = 0.3
>>> bw[0,0]
0
>>> bw[0,0] = 0.6
>>> bw[0,0]
0
```

If you care more about rounding to the nearest integer than always rounding down, then you can also wrap that computation in `np.round()`.

```
>>> bw[0,0] = np.round(0.3)
>>> bw[0,0]
0
>>> bw[0,0] = np.round(0.6)
>>> bw[0,0]
1
```

---

Numpy supports vectorisation, so you don't need to write explicit loops (which are also slower).

```
img = np.array(img)
bw = np.round(.299 * img[...,0] + .587 * img[...,1] + .114 * img[...,2]).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: if i run your code i'm getting error "TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @Shreyas You still need to do `img = np.array(img)` first. It's up there.

Comment: so if i would have done something like this:  bw[i,j] = np.round((.299*img[i,j,0])+(.587*img[i,j,1])+(.114*img[i,j,2])).   would that have worked.

Comment: @Shreyas Exactly. I guess you could omit the brackets in (.299*img[i,j,0]) because multiplications takes priority over addition, but that doesn't change the idea regardless.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, PIL images are stored in `uint8` format, so you can just replace `i = Image.fromarray(bw,'L')` with `i = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(bw),'L')`